# I made Runtime Gizmo but My gizmo's mouse drag is not accurate

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

I made runtime gizmo in project
but gizmo move correct drag is not correct

I have to move the mouse dragging part to the xyz axis, 
but I only move in the xy axis

i attempt innerproduct but failed

```
 public int HowToMove;
 private Vector3 mOffset; 
 private float mZCoord;

 void OnMouseDrag()
    {
      float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.root.position, 
     Camera.main.transform.position);
       switch (HowToMove)      
       {
            case 0:
               float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * (Time.deltaTime * 10 * distance);
            mOffset = Camera.main.transform.right * deltaX;
            CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position += mOffset;
            transform.root.position = (CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position);
                break;
            case 1:
                float deltaY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * (Time.deltaTime * 10 * distance);
                mOffset = Vector3.up * deltaY;
                CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position += mOffset;
                transform.root.position = (CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position);
                break;
            case 2:
                float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * (Time.deltaTime * 10 * distance);
                mOffset = Vector3.forward* deltaZ;
                CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position += mOffset;
                transform.root.position = (CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: could the problem be that for case 0 you use camera.transform (-space) while for both other cases you use world space (vector3.forward/up)?

Comment: @yes It's an error when it's fixed. ( vector3.right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem that did not drag correctly through xyz gizmo.

For example, when I turned the camera 180 degrees, I clicked xyz red (x axis) and moved up and down.
So I switched to the new code.

```
public class GizmoMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int HowToMove; //x y z 축 다르게 인스펙터창에서 설정이 되어있습니다.
    private Vector3 mOffset; 
    private float mZCoord;

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {

        Vector2 ve2 = CameraControls.originPos;
        switch (HowToMove)     
        {
            case 0:
                Vector2 XAxis = (new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")));
                float deltaX = Vector2.Dot(XAxis, ve2);
                mOffset = Vector3.left * deltaX * 0.3f;
                CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position += mOffset;
                transform.root.position = (CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position);
                break;
            case 1:
                Vector2 YAxis = (new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")));
                float deltaY = Vector2.Dot(YAxis, ve2);
                mOffset = Vector3.up * deltaY * 0.3f;
                CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position += mOffset;
                transform.root.position = (CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position);
                break;
            case 2:
                Vector2 ZAxis = (new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")));
                float deltaZ = Vector2.Dot(ZAxis, ve2);
                mOffset = Vector3.forward * deltaZ * 0.3f;
                CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position += mOffset;
                transform.root.position = (CameraControls.selectionObj.transform.position);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```